# How to change color of tag in Custom Html Tag in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a custom html Helper class like this below,

```
public static class LabelWithAstrickHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelWithAstrick<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        string resolvedLabelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName;
        if (metadata.IsRequired)
        {
            resolvedLabelText += "*";
            // resolvedLabelText += "<span style='color:red;'>*</span>";
        }
        return LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(html, expression, resolvedLabelText, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```

I used it like below in my view.

```
 @Html.LabelWithAstrick(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Now this will Show 'astrick' in black color, but I want to display this 'astrick' sign in red color.

please suggest How to do this.

Comment: Do you want the asterisk in red but the text in black? (if so you need to create 2 separate `<span>` elements within a `<label>` and style the `asterisk`

Comment: Since `color:red` is part of CSS selector, try creating CSS containing that selector and use it as `htmlAttributes` in your `span` tag (use built-in `TagBuilder` method to do that).

Comment: @Stephen Muecke : yes i want to show asterisk in red and label text in black.  Can you please edit my code or show some snippet to achieve this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to style the label text and the associated asterisk differently, then you cannot use the inbuilt `LabelFor()` method (the `HtmlHelper` methods encode the vale of the label text.

Instead you need to generate you own html in the method.

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelWithAstrick<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    string text = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? name.Split('.').Last();
    // Build 2 span elements containing text and the styled asterisk
    StringBuilder innerHtml = new StringBuilder();
    TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.InnerHtml = text;
    innerHtml.Append(span.ToString());
    if (metadata.IsRequired)
    {
        span = new TagBuilder("span");
        span.InnerHtml = "*";
        span.MergeAttribute("style", "color:red;"); // see notes
        innerHtml.Append(span.ToString());
    }
    // Create the label element and add the 2 span elements
    TagBuilder label = new TagBuilder("label");
    label.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name)));
    RouteValueDictionary attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    label.MergeAttributes(attributes, replaceExisting: true);
    label.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
    return new MvcHtmlString(label.ToString());
}
```

Note that I hard-coded an inline style for the asterisk as per your code, however I would recommend you use a class name instead using `span.AddCssClass("....");` and create a css definition for that class name to give you more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. you are the king:)